# newcommand problem

Tags: macros

I am trying to create a new command that represent one word larger than the text.

```
\newcommand {\Large}{\Large} is that right?
```

And then I have to integrate the top command in this

```
\newcommand{\smindexx}[2]{#2 \index{#2}}
```

I use `smindexx` as follow `\smindexx{\ITerm}{Test}` and Test should be larger than the other words.

How can I do that, have someone an idea?

Comment: `\renewcommand {\Large}{\Large} ` defines `\Large` to be a non-terminating infinite loop \Large expands to \Large which expands to ...  But it isn't clear what your intended behaviour is.

Comment: I have to write a command like \newcommand{\smindexx}[2]{#2 \index{#2}}, but the word should be in text larger, but not in the index. When the word is larger than the text the co author can see there is a problem with this word. When he correct this word, this command should be turn off. I hope its now clear....

Comment: Your question is very unclear. `\newcommand{\smindexx}[2]{#2 \index{#2}}` defines `\smindexx` to take two arguments but it discards `#1` and uses `#2` twice. You show usage as `\smindexx{\ITerm}{Test}` without saying what `\Iterm` is. As defined it would be discarded but assuming  the definition of `\smindexx` is changed you presumably want one argument to appear as large text at this point, and the other to go into the index?

Comment: \Iterm is not important, because i don't use it in this moment. Therefore is this like \newcommand{\smindexx}[2]{#2 \index{#2}}, because I dont use the first argument, but the second. \smindexx{\ITerm}{Test} Test is here the word in the text and it is the second argument, therefore he goes to the index.. But I want that the word Test in text appears larger..

Answer (score 3):

There are some issues with your approach:

Firstly, `\newcommand` takes the number of arguments in brackets `[2]` and then refers to the arguments as `#1` and `#2`. So your second code segment should be

```
\newcommand{\smindexx}[2]{#1 \index{#2}}
```

And would be called by

```
\smindexx{\ITerm}{Test}
```

so that part you got right.

Next, as David Carliste commented, defining `\Large` as `\Large` is redundant and may result in a loop. Furthermore, you can't use `\newcommand` for existing commands, but need `\renewcommand`.

If you simply want test to be `\Large` you can simply nest commands:

```
\newcommand{\smindexx}[2]%
{%
    #2%
    \index{%
              \Large{#2}%
          }%
}
```

The indentation is superfluous, but I hope it clarifies the idea. The part where you renewcommand `\Large` is unnecessary.

Comment: There is no compiler dependency. defining \Large to be \Large will loop if you then call \Large. Also the indentation will introduce white space in the output unless you `%` at the end of each line. I assume you would want `\Large` to be around `#2` (and inside `{}`) as otherwise it will go into the string to be indexed and sorted

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot about the `%`; and wasn't sure about the compiler dependency. Updated.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but don't you think this command is only for the index. Also the word in index is than larger, but not in text.

Comment: Ooo I am confused.. The top syntax don't work.. David can you please give me an example what do you mean.. Sorry my english is not so good.. :((

Comment: I see it now.. I am really confuses ;)

Comment: So I use the updated version of the newcommand, but this has no reactions on my pdf.. It's like before..

Answer (score 2):

I would guess (but it is only a guess as the question has so few details) that you want

```
\newcommand{\smindexx}[2]{{\Large#1}\index{#2}}
```

Then `\smindexx{abc}{xyz}` will typeset abc in large text at this point and make an index entry `xyz`.

As clarified in comments actually you want

```
\newcommand{\smindexx}[2]{{\Large#2}\index{#2}}
```

and re-use `#2` twice discarding `#1`.

Comment: It works ;) Thank you for your help.. My tutor wanted this with newcommand large because he thinks, I can create newcommand Large and then nested newcommand large in newcommand smiindexx. And then when he want this word again normal, he can do this with a newcommand normal.. I notice I don't understand him not really ;)

Comment: @blue oh that makes more sense, but without the loop. use a new name so `\myLarge` in the definition of `\smindexxx` instead of `\Large` then have `\newcommand\myLarge{\Large}` and later you can change that to `\newcommand\myLarge{}` so it does nothing

Comment: My Tutor said I can create then \newcommand{\MyLarge}{\Large} ist this syntax right? You wrote the syntax different. You mean \newcommand{\smindexx}[2]{{\MyLarge#2}\index{#2}}?

Comment: @blue yes that is the same as I wrote.

Comment: when I do this \newcommand{\smsindexspecial}[2]{\MyLarge{\url{#2}}\index{#2}}. I want that only websites appear larger. The Problem is when I use smsindexpexial for one website, after this website appear all the other words large, also the text.

Comment: @blue that's because you did not use the code supplied or that you yourself used 2 comments earlier. but incorrect scoping. `{` has to be before `\large` or `\mylarge` not after.

Comment: Like this \newcommand{\smsindexspecial[2]{\MyLarge\url{#2}}\index{#2}}

Comment: @blue NO!!!!!! As stated above several times `\newcommand{\smsindexspecial}[2]{{\MyLarge\url{#2}}\index{#2}} `